# Using set for unordered, unique list of elements

Tags: c++, c++03

In C++11 we have the option of using `std::unordered_set` if we require a list of elements that have no duplicates but order is not important.

In C++03 we don't have this options, although we can use the `std::set` to achieve something similar. Let's consider the following code:

```
std::set<ElementType, std::NotEqualTo<ElementType>> unorderedSet;
unorderedSet.insert(some_element);
unorderedSet.insert(other_element);
unorderedSet.insert(some_element);

//... more stuff with the set
```

This will, basically produce a set that will store the elements in the order they were inserted while preventing duplicates. Note that `ElementType` simply  **can't**  have less than or greater than operator. It doesn't make sense, semantically speaking.

Anyway, since I am using `std::NotEqualTo` instead of a `LessThan` functor, as it is requested by the set, I am not feeling very comfortable with this code. I do know that set is using something such as

```
if first element < second element
    //insert accordingly 
else if second element < first element
    //insert accordingly
else
   //they are equal
```

but in the same time, theoretically, my code will be failing if the checks were more strict such as

```
if first element < second element AND !(second element < first element)
//...
```

My questions are:

1. There are any potentially problems that could arise from using this construct?
2. What other alternatives I have to achieve the same thing in a more readable form? I do not plan to write my own unordered set just for this scenario and can't really use any external libraries. Only standard library available in C++03.

Edit: I am unable to make use of "less than" operator between my elements. I can decide if they are equal or not but I can't say which one is smaller than other. With the default set functor the code won't even compile as "operator<" is not found. This is why I wanted to model the functor with equal operator in the first case.

I am also aware that it is not valid, however, the code will produce the desired results. From my understanding it will expand to something such as:

```
if first element != second element
    // place first element
else if second element != first element
    // this is buggy, but should never be executed; first condition will always be true, unless the elements are equal.
else
    //here the elements are equal .
```

Comment: Using `std::NotEqualTo` is not valid. The comparator must generate a **strict weak ordering** for the code to work.

Comment: see: http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/set.html About half way down the page you will see the requirements on comparator `Compare     The key comparison function, a Strict Weak Ordering whose argument type is key_type; it returns true if its first argument is less than its second argument, and false otherwise. This is also defined as set::key_compare and set::value_compare.  less<Key>`. Then http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/StrictWeakOrdering.html is defined here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> My questions are:
>
> There are any potentially problems that could arise from using this construct?

Its not valid.
The code will not work as expected as the `std::set` requires the comparator type to generate a strict weak ordering between elements.

> What other alternatives I have to achieve the same thing in a more readable form? I do not plan to write my own unordered set just for this scenario and can't really use any external libraries. Only standard library available in C++03.

You can use `std::set` as an unordered container as is. If you have an unordered container it does not matter to you what order the elements are in. If they just happen to be ordered does that matter?

The reason for using `std::unordred_set` is that it provides faster access to the elements. You give up an ordered property to get better performance.

```
Container:           Insert     find
std::set             O(ln(n))  O(ln(n))
std::unordered_Set   O(1)      O(1)
```